# Call function with insert

Tags: oracle

I have a function that needs a string as parameter. It's always a insert. How do I make it work?  The double quotes for the values are not good syntactically

```
select inversor_insert('INSERT INTO clien(column1,column2) values('value1','value2')') 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following;

```
select inversor_insert(q'[INSERT INTO clien(column1,column2) values('value1','value2')]')
```

The q'[  ]' construct simply means that Oracle will treat anything within the brackets as it is written. you don't need to worry about quoting the quotes.